# Can not find the ".dealcard" method and the ".shuffle" method.

Tags: java, blackjack

**Deck** Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards
{
ArrayList deck = new ArrayList();
ListIterator deckIterator, tempDeckIterator;
int suit;
Random gen;

// Constructor
public DeckOfCards()
{
    gen = new Random(); // use this in a later method

    // for loop to create all cards in the deck
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        if(i < 13)
        {
            suit = 0;
        }
        else if(i < 26)
        {
            suit = 1;
        }
        else if(i < 39)
        {
            suit = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            suit = 3;
        }

        // create and add the card to the deck
        deck.add(new PlayingCard((i + 1) % 13, suit));
    }

    // shuffle the deck
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        shuffleDeck();
    }

   //printDeck();
}

public void printDeck()
{
    deckIterator = deck.listIterator();

    while(deckIterator.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(deckIterator.next());
    }
}

// shufle the deck of cards
public void shuffleDeck()
{
    ArrayList tempDeck = new ArrayList(); // used to hold rhe shuffled cards
    int pos; // the postion of the randomly generated card

    while(deck.size() > 0)
    {
        // Generate the card
        pos = gen.nextInt(deck.size());
        tempDeck.add((PlayingCard)deck.get(pos));
        deck.remove(pos);
    }

    // put all cards back into the deck
    tempDeckIterator = tempDeck.listIterator();
    while(tempDeckIterator.hasNext())
    {
        deck.add((PlayingCard)tempDeckIterator.next()); // top card from temp puts it in deck
    }
}
// get top card from the deck
public PlayingCard getTopCard()
{
    PlayingCard temp = (PlayingCard)deck.get(0);
    deck.remove(0);
    return temp;
}
// determine if any carsd are left int the deck
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(deck.size() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

This is my **BlackJackGui** Class.
This class is where the problem is at.
They can not find the symbol ".dealcard" and ".shuffle"
Do I have to change my **Deck** class or can I work around it?
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
if (gameInProgress == false) {
         message = "Click \"New Game\" to start a new game.";
         repaint();
         return;
      }
      playerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
      if ( playerHand.getBlackjackValue() > 21 ) {
         message = "You've busted!  Sorry, you lose.";
         gameInProgress = false;
      }
      else if (playerHand.getCardCount() == 5) {
         message = "You win by taking 5 cards without going over 21.";
         gameInProgress = false;
      }
      else {
         message = "You have " + playerHand.getBlackjackValue() + ".  Hit or Stand?";
      }
      repaint();
   }


   void doStand() {
           // This method is called when the user clicks the "Stand!" button.
           // Check whether a game is actually in progress.  If it is,
           // the game ends.  The dealer takes cards until either the
           // dealer has 5 cards or more than 16 points.  Then the
           // winner of the game is determined.
      if (gameInProgress == false) {
         message = "Click \"New Game\" to start a new game.";
         repaint();
         return;
      }
      gameInProgress = false;
      while (dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() <= 16 && dealerHand.getCardCount() < 5)
         dealerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
      if (dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() > 21)
          message = "You win!  Dealer has busted with " + dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() + ".";
      else if (dealerHand.getCardCount() == 5)
          message = "Sorry, you lose.  Dealer took 5 cards without going over 21.";
      else if (dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() > playerHand.getBlackjackValue())
          message = "Sorry, you lose, " + dealerHand.getBlackjackValue()
                                            + " to " + playerHand.getBlackjackValue() + ".";
      else if (dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() == playerHand.getBlackjackValue())
          message = "Sorry, you lose.  Dealer wins on a tie.";
      else
          message = "You win, " + playerHand.getBlackjackValue()
                                            + " to " + dealerHand.getBlackjackValue() + "!";
      repaint();
   }


   void doNewGame() {
          // Called by the constructor, and called by actionPerformed() if
          // the use clicks the "New Game" button.  Start a new game.
          // Deal two cards to each player.  The game might end right then
          // if one of the players had blackjack.  Otherwise, gameInProgress
          // is set to true and the game begins.
      if (gameInProgress) {
              // If the current game is not over, it is an error to try
              // to start a new game.
         message = "You still have to finish this game!";
         repaint();
         return;
      }
      DeckOfCards BJDeck = new DeckOfCards();   // Create the deck and hands to use for this game.
      dealerHand = new BlackjackHand();
      playerHand = new BlackjackHand();
      BJDeck.shuffle();
      dealerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );  // Deal two cards to each player.
      dealerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
      playerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
      playerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
```

Comment: where is the error (line number or something which can point the place of error in your code snippet)?

Comment: Where *exactly* do you believe you've declared a `dealCard` method or a `shuffle` method? Look carefully at the names you've *actually* declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeckOfCards` has methods named `getTopCard()` and `shuffleDeck()`, not `dealCard()` and `shuffle()`.

Change

```
BJDeck.shuffle();
```

to

```
BJDeck.shuffleDeck();
```

and

```
dealerHand.addCard( BJDeck.dealCard() );
```

to

```
dealerHand.addCard( BJDeck.getTopCard() );
```